# Populate data across monthly tabs

Tags: vba, excel

Not sure that I have been searching the right question...I have an Excel workbook with multiple worksheets within it representing each month of the calendar year. I want to be able to have data in a row copy from one worksheet to the next to the next month based on if criteria is met in a certain column.

For example:

In the worksheet "May2017", column A-L contains the data to be copied to "Jun2017".  However, the row of data will only be copied if the value in column D = "Inventory" or "Add to Inventory". If data in column D is updated then on the "Jun2017" sheet (value changes from "Inventory" to "Issued"), it will no longer carry over to the "Jul2017" sheet.

I want to do this for all worksheets, beginning with the "Jan2017" sheet.

Is this possible?

I having it working for February's data.  but the formula I have in column M gets replaced when data is copied.

Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Here is the VBA code:

Sub test()
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range, rngToCopy As Range
    Dim lastrow As Long
    'change Sheet1 and Sheet2 to suit
    Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Jan2017")
    Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Feb2017")

```
With ws1
    'assumung that your data stored in column A:B, Sheet1
    lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "m").End(xlUp).Row
    Set rng = .Range("A4:m" & lastrow)
    'clear all filters
    .AutoFilterMode = False
    With rng
        'apply filter
        .AutoFilter Field:=13, Criteria1:=1
        On Error Resume Next
        'get only visible rows
        Set rngToCopy = .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        On Error GoTo 0
    End With
    'copy range
    If Not rngToCopy Is Nothing Then rngToCopy.Copy Destination:=ws2.Range("A4")
    'clear all filters
    .AutoFilterMode = False
End With
Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

Comment: Not sure why you need VBA. This can be handled using pure spreadsheet functions.

Comment: Tried just the functions, but loose formulas when making edits

Comment: What functions did you use? Can you let us know more explicitly what you've tried?

Comment: I have vba and then the following code in column m:   =IF(OR(D4="Inventory",D4="Add to Inventory"),1,"").  When you make a change to column D, column M's formula is then overwritten.

Comment: Here is the vba code:  Sub test()
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range, rngToCopy As Range
    Dim lastrow As Long
    'change Sheet1 and Sheet2 to suit
    Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Jan2017")
    Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Feb2017")
    
    With ws1
        'assumung that your data stored in column A:B, Sheet1
        lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "m").End(xlUp).Row
        Set rng = .Range("A4:m" & lastrow)
        'clear all filters
        .AutoFilterMode = False

Comment: With rng
            'apply filter
            .AutoFilter Field:=13, Criteria1:=1
            On Error Resume Next
            'get only visible rows
            Set rngToCopy = .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
            On Error GoTo 0
        End With
        'copy range
        If Not rngToCopy Is Nothing Then rngToCopy.Copy Destination:=ws2.Range("A4")
        'clear all filters
        .AutoFilterMode = False
    End With
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    End Sub

Comment: Please edit that code into the question.  (I have, occasionally, pasted code from comments into questions on behalf of people, but it is difficult to work out where line breaks occur - so it is a lot easier / safer if you do it yourself.)

Comment: Thanks for the tip YowE3K.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you're after something like this:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()
    Dim monthsArr As Variant
    Dim iMonth As Long

    monthsArr = Array("Jan2017", "Feb2017", "Mar2017", "Apr2017", "Maj2017", "Jun2017", "Jul2017", "Aug2017", "Sep2017", "Oct2017", "Nov2017", "Dec2017") '<--| list your months tabs names
    For iMonth = LBound(monthsArr) To UBound(monthsArr) - 1 '<--| loop from first to second to last month tab name
        ProcessMonths CStr(monthsArr(iMonth)), CStr(monthsArr(iMonth + 1)) '<--| process the current "pair" of "first" and "subsequent" months
    Next
End Sub

Sub ProcessMonths(month1 As String, month2 As String)
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
    Dim nFiltered As Long
    Dim cellToPasteTo As Range

    Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(month1)
    Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(month2)
    With ws1 '<--| reference "1st month" worksheet
        .AutoFilterMode = False '<--| remove any previuous filtering
        With .Range("D4", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp)) '<--| reference its column "D" cells from row 4 (header) down to last not empty one
            .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=Array("Inventory", "Add to Inventory"), Operator:=xlFilterValues '<--| filter referenced cells with "Inventory" or "Add to Inventory" content
            nFiltered = Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(103, .Cells) - 1 '<--| count filtered cells skipping header
            If nFiltered > 0 Then '<--| if any filtered cells other than header
                Set cellToPasteTo = ws2.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1) '<--| set destination cell as the first empty one in "2nd month" worksheet column A
                With .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).Offset(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible) '<--| reference filtered referenced cells skipping header
                    .value = "Updated" '<--| change their value to "Updated"
                    Intersect(.Parent.Range("A:L"), .EntireRow).Copy cellToPasteTo '<--| copy their adjacent cells from columns A to L and paste them from destination cell downwards
                    Application.CutCopyMode = False '<--| release clipboard
                End With
            End If
        End With
        .AutoFilterMode = False '<--| remove filtering
    End With
End Sub
```